# App specific default settings in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm dividing my site into many small (hopefully reusable) apps, and I'm wondering how best to provide default settings that are overridable by the end-user?

I could do `getattr(settings, 'MYVAL', <default-value>)` everywhere but that's not DRY (nor pretty).

The best I've come up with is

```
myapp/appsettings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = ('my_dependency', 'myapp')
MYVAL = 42
```

then in `settings.py`:

```
from myapp import appsettings as MYAPP  # MYAPP must be UPPER CASE
INSTALLED_APPS = (.....)
INSTALLED_APPS += MYAPP.INSTALLED_APPS  # hide/encapsulate sub-dependencies
MYAPP.MYVAL = 5000                      # override
```

and then in view code:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
print settings.MYAPP.MYVAL
```

is this a reasonable way to do this, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

Use [django-appconf](https://github.com/jezdez/django-appconf).

It solves this problem in a nice way, I could quote its README here but that is a bit pointless.

Comment: looks fine... I'll have to try it.

Comment: It's cute, but perhaps a bit magical..?  It seems like it is breaking composability, i.e. you can't create a settings file from smaller settings files by saying `from .emailsettings import *; from .printersettings import *` (but perhaps the use-case for that doesn't intersect with app settings..?)

Comment: Actually I think that would still work, as these appconf settings are only used when there is no value in the normal Django settings.py, they're defaults. I like them (we use them in several subapps at work developed by different colleagues) because I can check conf.py to quickly see the available settings for the app.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't mess with `INSTALLED_APPS` this way as far as I'm concerned. Wrt/ other settings, the canonical solution is to

- import global settings from you appsettings.py file
- set values here depending on what's defined in gobal settings
- only use appsettings from within your application.

myapp/appsettings.py

```
from django.conf import settings


ANSWER = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_ANSWER", 42)
SOMETHING_ELSE = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_SOMETHING_ELSE", None)
```

myapp/models.py

```
from myapp import appsettings

class Question(object):
    answer = appsettings.ANSWER
```

Comment: My only objections to this method are (i) it makes it more difficult to spot the syntax error in your appsettings ;-)  and (ii) people looking at my code will not immediately understand that when I say `appsettings.ANSWER`, they should say `settings.MYAPP_ANSWER`... ps: why would you not want to hide sub-dependencies in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: You can use `appsettings.MYAPP_ANSWER` if you prefer, and syntax errors will be just as obvious (at least if you import appsettings in your models.py). And I don't like having to scan half a dozen or more files scattered in my project's AND virtualenv directories to find out which apps are installed - just a case of "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: `manage.py diffsettings`? (but I understand what you're saying).

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to have a `local_settings.py` file which supplements the project's `setting.py`.

**local_settings.py:**

```
XINSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myproject.app',
    ]
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ...
]

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError, exp:
    pass

try:
    INSTALLED_APPS += XINSTALLED_APPS  # defined in local_settings
except NameError:
    pass
```

Comment: My first impression is that it looks very verbose, and if someone checks in a local_settings.py that overrides e.g. `DEBUG` you'll have problems.

Comment: @thebjorn: You can be more selective about the values in local_settings.py that you want to import.  In our case we're using local settings to override the default settings in different environments, but they can't be overridden by the end users.

Comment: we do the same for global configuration settings, i.e. `settings/__init__.py` does `from .db_settings import *` which gets the correct database settings based on settings for `PROD/DEV/TEST`, `EXTERNAL/INTERNAL` server (which ultimately come from a list of known servers). Those aren't the kinds of settings an app should be overriding however, which is why I liked the automatic name-spacing of my suggestion.

Comment: Hmmm.. seems like you can't `from django.conf import settings` inside `local_settings.py` because of circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

**I have done In my last project Like this :**

```
from django.conf import settings

My_APP_ID = getattr(settings, 'My_APP_ID', None)

USER_EMIL_Is = getattr(settings, 'USER_EMIL_Is', Flase)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [django-zero-settings](https://github.com/aasmpro/django-zero-settings) which lets you define your defaults and a setting key for user settings, has auto-import strings, removed settings management, cache, pre-checks, etc.

as an example:

```py
from zero_settings import ZeroSettings

app_settings = ZeroSettings(
    key="APP",
    defaults={
        "INSTALLED_APPS": ["some_app"]
    },
)
```

and then use it like:

```py
from app.settings import app_settings

print(app_settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

or in your case you can also import it to your settings file and do something like:

```py
from app_settings import app_settings

SECRET_KEY = "secret_key"
# other settings ....
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    *app_settings.INSTALLED_APPS
]
```